# How do JavaScript versions correlate to ECMAScript versions?

Tags: javascript, version, mozilla, ecmascript-5

For example, [[].map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) was "implemented in JavaScript 1.6." Is that an ES5 method? How does the 1.6 correlate to an [ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) version?

Comment: "JavaScript 1.6" does not have any significant meaning outside Gecko-based browsers. Look through the [version overview pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/Special:Tags?tag=JavaScript_version_overviews) to browse the "changes history".

Comment: @RobW Thanks—I wasn't sure about that either (whether those versions were something that Mozilla came up with or whether they came from somewhere else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't really strict correspondences between the version numbers Mozilla uses and the ECMAScript standard's version numbers. There's a [table on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Version_correspondence) that might be what you're looking for -- you'll see that JavaScript 1.6 corresponds to ECMAScript 3 and then some additional extensions. `[].map` specifically was standardized in ECMAScript 5, but to my understanding, the feature was first introduced by Firefox before the ECMAScript 5 standard was even published. (Firefox 1.5 which included JavaScript 1.6 was released on November 29, 2005, and the standard appears to have been published in September 2009.)

Comment: There are actually lots of features that were first introduced in SpiderMonkey/Firefox in one of the post-1.5 JavaScript versions and later made their way into ECMAScript 5. There are also lots of features that stayed SpiderMonkey-only, some of these will likely be part of ECMAScript Harmony.