# finding javascript documentation for a specific version

Tags: javascript, rhino

When I run the `version()` command in rhino it prints `170`, how do I find documentation for that version of Javascript? I'm not sure if the `170` means ecma 170, javascript 1.7, etc.

Comment: Look for the ECMAScript specification. JavaScript 1.7 is just some numbering FF uses, but all environments today implement ES5, Rhino too probably.

Comment: ty, found this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460913/how-do-javascript-versions-correlate-to-ecmascript-versions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460913/how-do-javascript-versions-correlate-to-ecmascript-versions

Comment: Info about Rhino versions and specific Javascript feature support here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Overview

Comment: Here's some info about new Javascript features added to Rhino 170: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/New_in_Rhino_1.7R1

Answer (score 0):

stole this from [How do JavaScript versions correlate to ECMAScript versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460913/how-do-javascript-versions-correlate-to-ecmascript-versions)

There aren't really strict correspondences between the version numbers Mozilla uses and the ECMAScript standard's version numbers. There's a table on Wikipedia that might be what you're looking for -- you'll see that JavaScript 1.6 corresponds to ECMAScript 3 and then some additional extensions. [].map specifically was standardized in ECMAScript 5, but to my understanding, the feature was first introduced by Firefox before the ECMAScript 5 standard was even published. (Firefox 1.5 which included JavaScript 1.6 was released on November 29, 2005, and the standard appears to have been published in September 2009.)